# Tkinter Combobox Python

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter, combobox

I have used this Tkinter Combobox for getting a value from the user. It does the same and after getting the user input, the selected value is not assigned to that variable. And the twist is, it is an empty STRING. How can I assign the selected value to a variable as a FLOAT?

**My CODE:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('350x200')
combo = Combobox(window)
combo['values']= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
f11=combo.current(1) 
combo.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

I need to get the user input value to be assigned to f11 and add it with 50.

Note: I have tried this:f1=float(f11), but it throws an error of
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Thanks in advance for your timely help..

Comment: Try printing `f11`. Is it something useful? It looks like it is an empty string (`""`). Why do you need it anyways? What are you going to use it for?

Comment: btw You would need to call it in a function or sth otherwise it will work like once and that's it

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, after selecting a value from the drop-down menu, it is not assigned to that variable, f11.

Comment: @Matiiss How to assign the selected value to a variable as a FLOAT type?

Comment: use `float(variable)` but You have to make sure that `variable` can be converted to float

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you, but the selected number value is even not assigned to that variable, f11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DoubleVar()` for the `textvariable` option of `Combobox()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('350x200')
f11 = DoubleVar()
combo = Combobox(window, textvariable=f11)
combo['values']= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
combo.grid(column=0, row=0)
combo.current(1)
val = f11.get()
print(val, type(val))
window.mainloop()
```

And the output in console:

```
2.0 <class 'float'>
```

---

Another example to show the value of the variable inside a callback:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('350x200')
f11 = DoubleVar()
combo = Combobox(window, textvariable=f11, state="readonly")
combo['values']= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
combo.grid(column=0, row=0)
def on_change(event):
    val = f11.get()
    print(val, type(val))
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_change)
combo.current(0)
window.mainloop()
```

The value selected will be shown in console whenever the selection is changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works.. But the value always sticks to 2 even though I have selected 5. Any suggestion????

Comment: @SANNASICHAKRAVARTHY Example added to show the value inside a callback whenever the selection is changed.

Comment: Great.. It works, thank you so much.. But my aim is to add the selected value with a fixed 50. But, I can't use this "val" to be added with 50.  Is there any solution???

Comment: `val = f11.get() + 50` does not suit your case?

Comment: Yes, it suits.. But it won't stored in WORKSPACE..  The "val" is not stored in the workspace. That's the problem, gentleman..

Comment: Then you can use another `DoubleVar()` to replace `val`.

Comment: Yes, I too tried that and it worked greatly.. Thank you so much, CODE GIANT..